# Filling out our W4 correctly

Tags: taxes, payroll-taxes, form-w-4

So we recently got married and now I'm trying to figure out our W4. I make 77k a year and she's around 68k a year. Her stub shows Single-0 and mine is Married-1. I read through a bunch of articles and even tried a couple of paycheck calculators. Damn thing is so confusing. Bottom line, what's the easiest way to figure out the minimum amount of taxes we should be withholding from our paychecks.

Answer (score 2):

Tax programs can help you with that (both H&R Block and TurboTax know how to calculate this). You can also talk to your tax professional, if you have any, it should take them 5 minutes, so if you're a paying tax preparation customer, you can definitely expect this to be a free service.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices. One is to get the W4 form a copy for each of you, and run through the form. It asks the questions to properly calculate your withholding allowances.
The other way is to do a dry run of your taxes. If your income is regular, now that the year is half over, you have a good idea how the year will end. Then get a copy of Circular E (aka Publication 15), and calculate the proper withholding for the rest of this year.